# Structure of windows service with desktop GUI application

Tags: c#, windows-services

Ok so I have created a visual studio 2013 solution with two C# projects in it, one Win form application and one windows service. I am using advanced installer 11.6 to create my installation package, I am specifically employing the built in service installer function, which seems to work fine.

The win form has some buttons on it, when I click the button it calls a method and passes a number as an argument (the number corresponds to a command for the service). The method then uses a pipe to send this argument to the windows service. I want the windows service to be always listening for these commands... and when it receives the command code, it initiates that action.

Problem is that I definitely do not have my service structured properly and I may be incorrectly using pipes so I need some advice. I think my service is just running once like a script at the moment although I am not sure. It also looks like the command from the win forms app is not just trying to send data to the service, but seems to be attempting to start a new instance of the service (getting an error about the service not being able to be started from a command line or debugger... but it shouldn't be *Starting anything from the win form).

Anyway here is the code for the method in the win form that sends data to the service.

Win Form Method

```
private void pipe_server(byte _command)
    {
        //create streams
        var sender = new AnonymousPipeServerStream(PipeDirection.Out,   HandleInheritability.Inheritable);

        //start client, pass pipe ids as command line parameter 
        string clientPath = @"C:\\test\\My_Service.exe";
        string senderID = sender.GetClientHandleAsString();

        var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(clientPath, senderID);
        startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        Process clientProcess = Process.Start(startInfo);

        //release resources handlet by client
        sender.DisposeLocalCopyOfClientHandle();

        //write data
        sender.WriteByte(_command);
    }
```

And here is the service.

```
public partial class My_Service : ServiceBase
{
    public My_Service()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;

        //Change the following line to match. 
        ServicesToRun = new
            System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase[] { My_Service() };
        System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);

        pipe_client(args);
    }

    //method that listens for commands from the GUI and parses them
    static void pipe_client(string[] args)
    {
        string parentSenderID;

        //get pipe handle id
        parentSenderID = args[0];

        //create streams
        var receiver = new AnonymousPipeClientStream(PipeDirection.In, parentSenderID);

        //read data
        int dataReceive = receiver.ReadByte();

        //parse commands
        if (dataReceive == 1)
        {
            do_method_1();
        }

        else if (dataReceive == 2)
        {
            do_method_2();
        }

        else if (dataReceive == 3)
        {
            do_method_3();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For a start, it might be good to test if your communication method works WinForms->WinForms.  It might simplify debugging, if you try it that way, first.

Comment: Also, starting my_service.exe from forms app?  If you are using Windows Service, it's lifetime is managed by SCM (google it) and not directly by you.  And if you start my_service.exe, it will start second instance of it, etc. etc.

Comment: Ok how would I go about just referencing an existing instance of the service. The service is installed as part of the MSI package created by advanced installer and is set to run automatically. The service does install properly and I see it running and in the list under services.msc. But I have no clue on how to send this command to an existing instance of the service.

Comment: You can't use an anonymous pipe to communicate between unrelated processes.  You have to use a named pipe.

Answer (score -1):

The example located here would help you achieve what you're looking to do: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.pipes.anonymouspipeclientstream%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

All it looks like you need to do, is set up some form of loop to poll the stream for specific commands.  The example provided shows how to setup a StreamReader and a do loop which checks a string pulled from the StreamReader.ReadLine() command until there's something recognized.

```
//method that listens for commands from the GUI and parses them
static void pipe_client(string[] args)
{
    string parentSenderID;

    //get pipe handle id
    parentSenderID = args[0];

    //create streams
    var receiver = new AnonymousPipeClientStream(PipeDirection.In, parentSenderID);

    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(receiver))
    {
                // Display the read text to the console 
                string temp;

                // wait for message from server.
                do
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("waiting for message...");
                    temp = sr.ReadLine();
                }
                while (!<temp in some check variable or array>);

                switch(temp)
                { 
                   handle everything here.  
                }
    }
}
```

Comment: The OP needs named pipes, not anonymous pipes.

Comment: But he's writing a service, so the service he's communicating with won't have a parent-child relationship with the GUI.

Comment: You are correct, after further investigation on the issue, my response is invalid.